# Symfony form default value from extended class

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to set default values for a form in symfony but it doesn't seem to work. The form is mapped to an entity.

I know that if you set the value in the entity then that will be the default value, but in my case the entity extends another class ( a mapped superclass ), and my field is on that class.

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
abstract class BaseEntity implements CustomEntityInterface
{
  protected $choiceField = 30;

 [ getters, setters, ... ]
}

class MyEntity extends BaseEntity
{
  [other attributes, getters, setters, ...]
}
```

The choiceField should default to 30 but it doesn't. (It's a choice field for minutes and it's populated with values from 5 to 60 with a step of 5)

I know I could redeclare $this->choiceField in MyEntity but it doesn't seems right to me. Is there any other solution?

Thanks,
Stev

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
abstract class BaseEntity implements CustomEntityInterface
{
    protected $choiceField = 30;
}
```

?

Default value form Symfony2 forms can be simply set during form creation:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) 
{
    $builder
        ->add('choiceField', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Field',
            'data' => 'Default value'
        ))
        // ...
    ;
}
```

and also with setting entity property value.

Comment: Sorry for my bad copy-pasting from the IDE :),

Comment: If I set the value in the BaseEntity it doesn't use it in the form. And I'm curios if it's possible to set this value in just one place, preferably in the BaseEntity.